# combo box ajaxcontrol

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have a filter panel with 5-6 combo boxes ajax control tool kit..

i want this filter panel to be visible false by default.. and toggle it(show/hide) on client click using java script

however when i have my filter panel as visible = false runat=server java script does not get the object

and if i do code behind.. filterpanel.attributes.add("style",display:none)
filterpanel.attributes.add("style",visibilty:hidden)

the combo box throws a runtime error..

i've searched on the net which says.. combo box is difficult to render inside a panel.. whose default property is initially false!

Comment: combo box is an ajax control tool kit.. runtime error i get is invalid argument..default visible property of panel = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `<select>` elements have to be [rendered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751.aspx) (but not necessarily [visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531180.aspx)) in order to reliably access their dimension properties.

So `display: none;` won't work because the elements are not rendered, and `visibility: hidden;` will partially work because the elements are rendered, so space is allocated for them on the page, but hidden, so that space will remain empty.

A third solution is to render the container as usual, but make it absolutely [positioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531140.aspx) outside of the browser viewport:

```
filterPanel.Attributes.Add("style",
    "position: fixed; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;");
```

That way, the panel and its contents won't be visible, but the size of the `<select>` elements will be properly computed.

On the client side, the formula to show the panel becomes:

```
document.getElementById("filterPanelClientID").style.position = "static";
```

And to hide it again:

```
document.getElementById("filterPanelClientID").style.position = "fixed";
```

You can test a jQuery-based implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cJh9F/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if you set Visible="false" on a server control, it won't render any of the HTML elements, including the combo boxes.  Hiding the panel using the following is AJAX friendly:

```
<asp:Panel id="p" runat="server" style="display:none">

</asp:Panel>
```

Which will render a DIV and all your drop downs, but hide them from view, allowing you to toggle the div's visibility.

Comment: hey.. i tried.. doing this.. but still the same error occurs..as soon as the page loads.. the combo box drop downs throws a run time error in script resource dynamic created file style.width = bestwidth + px where the best width = -2

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the "display: none" to the panel, only "visibility: hidden":

```
filterpanel.Attributes.Add("style", "visibilty: hidden");
```

This will hide your panel (the `<div>` I suppose) but reserve the required space (and therefore will allow the dimension-related properties of the corresponding DOM element to have the right values).

Of course you'll see an empty spot but you could probably resolve this issue by playing with the styles of an element (maybe by nesting the panel inside another element and by applying styles to that element instead of doing that on the panel itself).

Comment: which element should i place the panel to hide??.. and apply style?.. do i take another panel?.. wont it have the same effect?

Comment: @prateek: First, try my solution on the panel that contains your combo boxes. If it helps then wrap a DIV element around your panel and make it invisible by setting "height" and "line-height" CSS properties to "0px" (you might need to apply "overflow: hidden" as well). Test it. If it doesn't throw an error then change your logic of displaying the panel so it can also remove those CSS styles from the parent DIV (otherwise you won't see the panel since the parent DIV is shrinked).

Comment: the panel that is containing my combo boxes.. i tried making it hidden as you said..it does help.. i just see the dropdown button of the combo box.. and white spot.. please tell me the logic to remove the css styles from parent div..i can test it totally then.. thank you so much

Comment: I guess you've already figured that out (with the help from Frédéric Hamidi) ;-)